# Why won't my tableOutput update unless I create a reactive value in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I wrote the shiny app bellow and it is working that way. It is a simple control to select a material from a list (a column from a tibble) and then output a table containing all the columns from that tibble, but just the row corresponding to the selected material. What I don't understand is why I have to create the reactive value (that I named "materialInfo") on the server function in order to update `tableOutput("materialInfo")` on the dashboardBody.

Why won't simply `output$materialInfo <- Material %>% filter({Material == input$matId}) %>% renderTable()` do the job? Any ideas? tks

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(feather)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

Material = as_tibble(read_feather("ListaMateriais.feather"))

# Define UI 
ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    dashboardHeader(title="Setup"),
    
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Material",tabName = "material",icon = icon("th"))
        )
    ),
    
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "material",
                    selectInput("matId","Selecione o material",choices = Material$Material),
                    tableOutput("materialInfo")
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    materialInfo <- reactive({Material %>%
        filter(Material == input$matId)
    })
    output$materialInfo <- renderTable(materialInfo())
}
 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `output$materialInfo <- Material %>% filter({Material == input$matId}) %>% renderTable()` it's not reacting, is because input$matId is called **before** entering the reactive content as common code, what get's piped into renderTable() is already 'processed' a.k.a evaluated.

Comment: I see. Great. Tks